# Generate short but globally unique Message-Id

Tags: node.js, rfc2822

I have build a module that generates a very unique `Message-Id`, but I've been asked to shorten it, so I wonder how short I can make it, so it is still RFC 2822 valid and will not get caught in spam filters.

I see Python [generates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7688b44387d116522ff53c0927169db45969f0e/Lib/email/utils.py#L202-L223) one that is about 41 chars long, which seems a bit too short.

Any suggestions?

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');

// inspired by http://www.jwz.org/doc/mid.html#3

module.exports = function (hostname) {
  var hrtime = process.hrtime();
  var microseconds = hrtime[0] * 1000000 + hrtime[1] / 1000;
  var token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
  var b36 = parseInt(token, 16).toString(36);
  var result = '<';
  result += microseconds;
  result += b36;
  result += '@' + hostname;
  result += '>';
  return result;
};
```

Comment: I think you need to share what the objective is.  So, shorten your id to what total length?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps  [cuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cuid)  is  suitable for you?